# Objectweb ASM Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target on unmodified method in updated class

Tags: java

I have a program which takes in a class (using ClassReader) and then creates a ClassVisitor which, based on the attributes of the class adds two new methods (well actually one constructor and one method) and then writes it out through a ClassWriter.

After running this code if I try to use this class, the Java loader fails with a VerifyError on the ARETURN at the end of a method which was already there, i.e. not one of the ones I added.

The class was compiled using Scala-3 (Dotty), and runs quite happily if I use the compiler output rather than the modified class.  The method which fails in question is a generated artifact of a  case class (productElement).

I am using ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES.  Should I be using COMPUTE_INSERTED_FRAMES so that ASM only tries to adjust the frames of the new classes I have added or have I miss-understood COMPUTE_INSERTED_FRAMES - the javadoc for the constant is not very clear?

I have looked at the two class files, before and after adding the new methods and extracted the method that was just copied but which now shows an error.

They are very slightly different in the very last frame entry.

As generated by the scala compiler, the last frame entry was:-

```
frame_type = 255 /* full_frame */
offset_delta = 0
locals = [ class uk/co/dga/openbusiness/ubl/Code, int, int ]
stack = [ class java/lang/Object ]
```

and after this method has been copied by ASM:-

```
frame_type = 255 /* full_frame */
offset_delta = 0
locals = [ class uk/co/dga/openbusiness/ubl/Code, int, int ]
stack = [ class scala/Option ]
```

Diff reports no other changes between the two method's code.

The error that is reported is:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 175
Exception Details:
  Location:
    uk/co/dga/openbusiness/ubl/Code.productElement(I)Ljava/lang/Object; @175: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/String' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'scala/Option' (stack map, stack[0])
  Current Frame:
    bci: @60
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'uk/co/dga/openbusiness/ubl/Code', integer, integer }
    stack: { 'java/lang/String' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @175
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'uk/co/dga/openbusiness/ubl/Code', integer, integer }
    stack: { 'scala/Option' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 1b3d 1caa 0000 0099 0000 0000 0000 0009
    0000010: 0000 0035 0000 003f 0000 0049 0000 0053
    0000020: 0000 005d 0000 0067 0000 0071 0000 007b
    0000030: 0000 0085 0000 008f 2ab6 012a a700 7300
    0000040: 00bf 2ab6 012d a700 6900 00bf 2ab6 0130
    0000050: a700 5f00 00bf 2ab6 0133 a700 5500 00bf
    0000060: 2ab6 0136 a700 4b00 00bf 2ab6 0139 a700
    0000070: 4100 00bf 2ab6 013c a700 3700 00bf 2ab6
    0000080: 013f a700 2d00 00bf 2ab6 0142 a700 2300
    0000090: 00bf 2ab6 0145 a700 1900 00bf bb01 4759
    00000a0: 1bb8 014d b601 51b7 0154 bf00 00bf bfb0
    00000b0:                                        
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@56,Integer)
    full_frame(@63,{},{Object[#343]})
    append_frame(@66,Object[#2],Integer,Integer)
    full_frame(@73,{},{Object[#343]})
    append_frame(@76,Object[#2],Integer,Integer)
    full_frame(@83,{},{Object[#343]})
    append_frame(@86,Object[#2],Integer,Integer)
    full_frame(@93,{},{Object[#343]})
    append_frame(@96,Object[#2],Integer,Integer)
    full_frame(@103,{},{Object[#343]})
    append_frame(@106,Object[#2],Integer,Integer)
    full_frame(@113,{},{Object[#343]})
    append_frame(@116,Object[#2],Integer,Integer)
    full_frame(@123,{},{Object[#343]})
    append_frame(@126,Object[#2],Integer,Integer)
    full_frame(@133,{},{Object[#343]})
    append_frame(@136,Object[#2],Integer,Integer)
    full_frame(@143,{},{Object[#343]})
    append_frame(@146,Object[#2],Integer,Integer)
    full_frame(@153,{},{Object[#343]})
    append_frame(@156,Object[#2],Integer,Integer)
    full_frame(@171,{},{Object[#343]})
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@174,Object[#343])
    full_frame(@175,{Object[#2],Integer,Integer},{Object[#282]})

        at uk.co.dga.openbusiness.ui.App.<init>(App.scala:41)
        at uk.co.dga.openbusiness.ui.App$.main(App.scala:123)
        at uk.co.dga.openbusiness.ui.App.main(App.scala)
```

and changing the option on the ClassWriter from COMPUTE_FRAMES to 0 cures the problem.

Comment: There is no `COMPUTE_INSERTED_FRAMES` in [the official API](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html). Besides that, show what you have tried and the exact error you get.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the difference between the two javap reported stackframes.  This mirrors the error shown by the java loader.  I also notice that I am using ,0 as the second argument on the ClassReader.accept method, but that there are some options, which again I do not quite understand, which might be relevant.

Comment: When you use `COMPUTE_FRAMES`, the frames calculated by ASM may differ from the original frames. That, however, does not imply that they are wrong. The full context would be helpful, i.e. the code you’re using for the transformation and the complete message of the `VerifyError`. Don’t let others ask you for the relevant information over and over again.

Comment: There seems to be multiple occurrences of unreachable code, but that’s unlikely the problem. As said, the full transformation code is needed. Did you override `ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass`?

Comment: Yes I did, but only to introduce a custom classloader as the classes being transformed are not on the classpath.  If I could pass my classloader into ASM or if ASM used the contextClassloader rather than the classloader than loaded the ClassWriter then I would not need my own getCommonSuperClass - but I copied the code line for line other than selecting the classloader.

Comment: There should be a `getCommonSuperClass("java/lang/String", "scala/Option")` call when ASM tries to compute the problematic method’s last stack frame, which apparently resulted in `"scala/Option"` rather than `"java/lang/Object"`. This could be workarounded when using visitor chaining by enabling optimizations which copy unchanged methods as-is without recalculating stack frames (while still doing that for new methods), but as said, for more specific suggestions, we need to know the actual transformation code.